# Reopen own "Closed-Reopened-Closed" Question

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I would like to point your attention to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4147918/191776

If I can vote to reopen my question for one reason, manage to get it reopened, then again have it closed by someone for another reason, why can't I vote again for reopening it?
Does this go against SO ethics?

Answer (score 1):

You can only vote once for open/close.  Which is a good thing. In the past we had some serious open/close wars.

I think the question is not an exact duplicate, so I have voted to reopen. Wait and see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 0):

If people can't seem to decide if you question is a dupe or not, you might consider editing to add more detail.